# Unable to change Asp Identity Table Names..... Asp .Net Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to change the identity table's name. I googled around and found the following methods:

The first one:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);


    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "Users");
    });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "Roles");
    });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationRoleClaim>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "RoleClaims");
    });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "UserRoles");
    });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "UserLogins");
    });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "UserClaims");
     });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserToken>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "UserTokens");
    });
 }
```

The second one:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRoleClaim>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserToken>().ToTable("UserTokens");
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    }
```

All the generic names, like ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, etc., have "int" as their primary key.

The **ApplicationDbContext** and **StartUp** looks like the following

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
```

**StartUp class**

```
       services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

If you noticed, on the start-up class, I didn't add an **int** on `AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().` Because, a compiler error keeps showing up saying **"Not supported....".**

And I did the following to remove the old database and migration

```
$ drop-database
$ remove-migration
```

To add the new configuration

```
$ add-migration Initial
$ update-database
```

I found that only the users and roles tables are changed, but not the others (AspUserRoles, AspUserClaim, etc.).

**FYI:**

I am using Visual Studio 2017. My project uses the default Web Application with *Individual User Account* selected and **.NET Core 2.** I am also using Pomela.EntityFramework.MySql as my database provider.

My question is: "What am I doing wrong?" Or what's changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `IdentityDbContext` about all of your custom types. In order to do that, you'll need to expand out the generics you pass through to `IdentityDbContext`, like so:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,
    ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken>
```

Comment: I have a same code to define my DbContext class and used same codes like what @ash has used but all of the Identity tables have _AspNet_ prefix in the database yet! Do you have any tip 4 me please?

Comment: @RAM There's nothing obvious that stands out. If you decide to ask this as a new question with your specific details, feel free to let me know and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Add the table names you want as per code below:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
      base.OnModelCreating(builder);    
      builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
      builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");
      builder.Entity<ApplicationRoleClaim>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
      builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
      builder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
      builder.Entity<ApplicationUserToken>().ToTable("UserTokens");
      builder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
   }
   ```
2. Open the Package Manager Console and run the following command:

   **Add-Migration MyTablesRenamed**

   You will see a new file created in the application with all commands to rename the tables and some more commands.
3. **Run Update-Database**

Done, your tables should be renamed now.